# Use Kamcord on non Cocos2d app

Tags: ios, objective-c, record

I am implementing according to kamcord tutorial :

https://github.com/kamcord/kamcord-ios-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started#wiki-kamcord-initialization

My app is a simple ios app not using the cocos2d game engine.
and for some reason I cannot see it working.
Here is the code implemented in app delegate :

```
_view_controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
// that will present the Kamcord UI.
[Kamcord setDeveloperKey:@"key"
         developerSecret:@"secret"
                 appName:@"appName"
    parentViewController:_view_controller];
```

and I call this methods from the viewController:

```
- (IBAction)stopRecording:(id)sender {
    [Kamcord stopRecording];
    NSLog(@"Stop");
}

- (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender {
    [Kamcord startRecording];
    NSLog(@"Start");
}

-(IBAction)showUpKamcord{
    [Kamcord showViewInViewController:self];
    NSLog(@"kamcord");
}
```

First I start recording, then stop and after that I am showing the view,
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an older question, but for those that stumble upon it looking for a solution to record your non-Open GL based screens, there is a project called ASScreenRecorder https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder that allows you to record your UIKit based app screens and it's extremely simple to get working.

Answer (score 1):

Kamcord only works with OpenGL views. It does not record UIKit, so that won't work if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I contacted Kamcord about this today, unfortunately they still don't support UIKit.

Comment: Yes, Kamcord does not support UIKit yet. Including their examples which are based of Open GL based application.